# Prove $\sum_{cyc} a(a-b)(a-2b) \ge 0$.Where $a,b,c \ge 0$

Tags: inequality, substitution, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way

I’ve tried splitting this into the sum of two Chinese Dumbass triangles:
\begin{gather}
\quad0\\
{-}5\quad0\\
\hskip1.5em0\quad\hskip.3em15\hskip.6em{-}5\hskip1em\\
0\quad{-}5\quad0\hskip1.2em0
\end{gather}
And
\begin{gather}
1\\
2\quad2\\
2\quad{-}15\quad2\\
1\qquad2\quad2\qquad1
\end{gather}
And that fails. Any hint or help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the numbers $a,b,c$$?

Comment: They are nonnegative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let 
  $$ f(a,b,c) := a(a-b)(a-2b)+b(b-c)(b-2c)+c(c-a)(c-2a). $$
The key observation is that the coefficient of $x^2$ in $f(a+x,b+x,c+x)$ is 
  $$ -(a-b)-(b-c)-(c-a) = 0; $$
that is, $f(a+x,b+x,c+x)$ is *linear* in $x$. Furthermore, the coefficient of $x$ is
\begin{multline*}
  -2b(a-b) - 2c(b-c) - 2a(c-a) \\
     = (a^2+b^2-2ab) + (b^2+c^2-2bc) + (c^2+a^2-2ac) \ge 0. 
\end{multline*}
It follows that $f(a+x,b+x,c+x)$ is an increasing function of $x$. Therefore, assuming for definiteness that $\min\{a,b,c\}=a$, we get
  $$ f(a,b,c) \ge f(0,b-a,c-a). $$
That is, the general case reduces to that where $a=0$, and this special case is very easy to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Thus, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}a(a-b)(a-2b)=2a(u^2-uv+v^2)+u^3-3u^2v+2uv^2+v^3\geq$$
$$\geq4\left(\frac{u^3}{4}\right)+uv^2+uv^2+v^3-3u^2v\geq7\sqrt[7]{\left(\frac{u^3}{4}\right)^4\left(uv^2\right)^2v^3}-3u^2v=\left(\frac{7}{\sqrt[7]{256}}-3\right)u^2v\geq0.$$